# Passing ngInit $index back to script

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, visualization

i'm currently developing a visualization tool that involves AngularJS and D3.js.
I need to pass the index of the ng-init back to the script to uniquely set the ids and classes of multiple charts.

here is a sample of my code.

```
<body ng-app = "chartApp" ng-init="charts = [[4,2,3,4,42,32], [123,52,14,22,12], [53,72,76,13,13], [143,652,76,112]]">
<donut-chart data="chart" ng-repeat="chart in charts"> {{ $index + 1 }} </donut-chart>
```

i want to bring $index back to the script so i can set the id or class attr uniquely

```
var chartApp = angular.module('chartApp', [])

chartApp.directive('donutChart', function(){
function link(scope, el){
    var data = scope.data
    var color = d3.scale.category20()
    var el = el[0]
    var width = el.clientWidth
    var height = el.clientHeight
    var min = Math.min(width, height)
    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null)
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(min / 2 * 0.9)
                .innerRadius(min / 2 * 0.5)
    var svg = d3.select(el).append('svg')
                .attr({width: width, height: height})
                .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')')

    svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(pie(data))
        .enter().append('path')
            .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "arc" + (i+1); })
            .style('stroke', 'white')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i){ return color(i) })

}

return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { data: '=' }
}
})
```

i have already set the arcs of the donut charts uniquely but i can't set the donut charts itself uniquely.

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

wow, can't believe that the answer was very simple,
i just had to add a new scope to pass `$index` back to the script.

got the answer after a few minutes of posting this. 
updating this post for anyone who'll maybe find this useful.